# Descent of line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of a finite group $G$. Then what are the line bundles on $P(V)$, descent to the G.I.T. quotient $P(V)/G$ ? and why ?

Comment: If you want a line bundle to descend, you need to make it $G$-equivariant.  What sort of question do you mean to ask when you say "why?"?

Comment: @S. Carnahan : a $G$-linearization on a sheaf is enough to descend only if the action of $G$ on $P(V)$ is free, which is not the case as soon as $V$ admits a one dimensional sub-representation for instance. Generally, a $G$-linearization  allows to descend to the quotient stack (more or less by definition) which lies strictly above the usual quotient, if the action is not free.

Answer (score 1):

If G is finite, do you need to take the GIT quotient? Maybe just the usual categorical would work.

A necessary condition is that for any point x of P(V) its stabilizer acts trivially on the fiber of your line bundle at x. The stabilizer would also be finite, and its action on the one-dimensional fiber factors through the quotient by the commutator subgroup. Since the values of the one dimensional representation homomorphism must be roots of unity, after taking appropriate tensor power the action will become trivial. Say, if you consider O(n) where n is the order of G.